# Workaround for React Native flexbox algorithm — boxes not stretching based on text height

Tags: flexbox, react-native

**I want to implement something like this** with React Native:

[image: outcome-screenie]

... notice how the grey line must run through top to bottom; the height of the 'row' is dictated by the amount of text there is in that step.

This is what I did:

1. Let's build the circular image node. You can see this running at https://rnplay.org/apps/NRZAFg. So far so good. I've marked the underlying container (which I'll call `lhsContainer`) with light red. The container flexes to fill the whole row.

[image]

2. Okay, let's try making sure the grey lines flex to fill to both the top and bottom of `lhsContainer`. Easy: I just add `height: 100` to the view that contains it (`styles.container`). This works fine:

[image]

3. Next, incorporating the text. I want the height of the row (and therefore `lhsContainer`) to be given by the text.  This DOESN'T work fine. The grey line doesn't flex to the bottom of the container! :

[image]

Autolayout would have done the right thing here (being a fancy-pantsy constraint solver), but FlexBox doesn't.  (You can see this for yourself by uncommenting the code in [the playground app](https://rnplay.org/apps/NRZAFg)).

I believe using `row-reverse` would be one way to resolve this, but sadly [React Native doesn't support it yet](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/1942).

What's the workaround for this?

Comment: I've also raised an issue at React Native: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/1942

Comment: See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).